# I am receiving blank variables via PHP form email

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

I receive this in my email.  I receive a few a day and have no way of attempting to reach my potential customer.  I test the pages and they always seem to work.  If I leave form with blank entries it does error when I do my tests.  I would like to be able to solve this issue as I feel I am losing potential sales leads.

**Emails are received blank like below:**

Subject::

Email::

Alt Email::

Message::

---

```
<?php
$where_form_is="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].strrev(strstr(strrev($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),"/"));
mail("myemail@sample.com","PhpFormGenerator - Contact from Website","Form data:
Subject:: " . $_POST['field_1'] . " 
Email:: " . $_POST['field_2'] . " 
Alt Email:: " . $_POST['field_3'] . "
Message:: " . $_POST['field_4'] .
");
include("confirm.html");
?>
```

---

```
<BR/><!-- begin form -->
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data action=processor.php onSubmit="return validatePage1();"><ul class=mainForm id="mainForm_1">

<li class="mainForm" id="fieldBox_1">
<label class="formFieldQuestion" style="font-size: medium">
Sudject:&nbsp;*</label><select class=auto-style13 name=field_1 id=field_1 style="width: 415px; height: 24px"><option value=''></option>
<option>Sales</option>
<option>Product Questions</option>
<option>Payment Quesitons</option>
<option>Shipping Questions</option>
<option>Support</option>
<option>Other (Not Listed)</option>
</select></li>

<li class="mainForm" id="fieldBox_2">
<label class="formFieldQuestion" style="font-size: medium">Email:&nbsp;*</label><input class=auto-style20 type=email name=field_2 id=field_2 size=20 value="" style="background-image:url('dolls/inflatable/order/imgs/email.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;  padding: 2px 2px 2px 25px; width: 385px; height: 24px;"><label class="formFieldQuestion" style="font-size: medium; width: 228px;">Alt. Email 
or Re-Enter Email:&nbsp;*</label></li>
<li class="mainForm" id="fieldBox_3">
<input class=auto-style20 type=email name=field_3 id=field_3 size=20 value="" style="background-image:url('dolls/inflatable/order/imgs/email.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;  padding: 2px 2px 2px 25px; width: 385px; height: 24px;"></li>
<li class="mainForm" id="fieldBox_5">
</li>

<li class="mainForm" id="fieldBox_4">
<label class="formFieldQuestion" style="font-size: medium">
Message:&nbsp;*</label></li><textarea class=mainForm  name=field_4 id=field_5 cols=20 style="width: 400px; height: 85px; background: #FFFFFF; color: #000000"></textarea>


<!-- end of this page -->

<!-- page validation -->
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
<!--
function validatePage1()
{
retVal = true;
if (validateField('field_1','fieldBox_1','text',1) == false)
retVal=false;
if (validateField('field_2','fieldBox_2','text',1) == false)
retVal=false;
if (validateField('field_3','fieldBox_3','text',1) == false)
retVal=false;

if(retVal == false)
{
alert('Please correct the errors. Fields marked with an asterisk (*)');
return false;
}
return retVal;
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>

<!-- end page validaton -->



<!-- next page buttons -->
<li class="mainForm">
<input id="saveForm" class="auto-style6" type="submit" value="Submit" style="height: 47px; color: #000000; background-color: #CCCCCC; font-size: medium; border: #000000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; font-size: 100%; font-variant: normal; line-height: normal; width: 277px;" />
</li>

</ul>
</form>
<!-- end of form -->
<!-- close the display stuff for this page -->
```

---

I am new at this and used phpformgenerator to create this page.  All I really care about is getting the customer's email address.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you verifying that $_POST is actually set before sending this email? and are you sure your form is posting the variables correctly? (show us your form code)

Comment: You should have a condition met before processing, so bots won't trigger the e-mail. Something like if(isset($_POST['field_4'])){ wrap your page in this }

Comment: Form code has been added to the above post.  I am new at php and my biggest concern is missing a customer question or possible sale

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment not post an anwser but I don't have enough rep..

I really doubt you're loosing sales. This is probably a bot submitting which doesn't not have JS so that part just gets ignored.

It could also be a bot which scrapped the processor.php file name and now they're accessing that form directly. You could put in a:

```
if(isset($_POST["field_2"]))
```

type of test at the top of that page. You can then log if a bot is directly connecting to that page.